# Is it possible to point my domain to a DDNS?

Tags: domains, dns, ip-address, cname, isp

I have a server at home that I use for a multitude of things. The domain is currently hosted by GoDaddy. My problem isn't a huge one, but it is quite annoying and I would like it to work the way I want it to.

As far as I can tell the A record of a domain cannot be pointed to anything other than an IP address. That is a problem because my ISP refuses to give me a static external IP.

In response, I started using DuckDNS. My server has a cronjob that runs every few seconds. That cronjob tells DuckDNS what my external IP is.

I can then point the CNAME records of my domain to the DuckDNS subdomain. The problem here is that I cannot go to "example.com" but rather have to prefix the domain, I.E. "www.example.com".

Is there a place where I can host my domain that will provide a service similar to DuckDNS for free? I.E., my cronjob changes the A record of the domain?

Comment: Unfortunately recommendations for [external sites](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and services is considered off-topic here due to issues with spam and self-promotion. You could consider using a CDN to proxy your local site, and then use their API to change the IP address should your dynamic IP change. You'll then be able to setup your DNS anyway you like, with redirects (aka, "PageRules") as well.

Comment: This is something that can be easily done. People do this all the time. However, I cannot recommend a service and I am sure that most of us cannot either. Or at least not easily. We are professionals here and while some of use have servers at home, we probably all use static IP addresses. If your ISP will not give you a static IP address, then it is likely against the policies of the ISP to host websites. Check this before proceeding. Good luck!

Comment: Keep in mind that not all nameservers respect TTL records. Some will cache your IP for 6-24 hours regardless of the TTL. So, even if you update your IP promptly on "your" nameserver, there's no guarantee "the Internet" will see it immediately.

Comment: The question is if it is possible to point a domain to a DDNS -- that he later asked for where he could if it is not possible seems a flimsy reason to close the question.

Comment: Additionally, saying that the solution to needing a DDNS is to have a static IP is not an answer, especially when couched in language about how running something on a connection without a static IP is likely against the policies of the ISP. There are many legitimate reasons one would want a domain pointed to a server on a dynamic IP.